Failing To Setup Dynamic Enum Popout Menu
I'm trying to create a dynamic property (enum) but I just can't get it to show up when I press the button the trigger the operator (VonPanel_RiggingTools_Submenu_MassSetBoneConstraintSpace)
The enum (ExistingBoneConstraints_enum) is supposed to grab all the selected bones and provide me with a list of the constraints on those bones (getselectedbonesforenum()) as well as other enums providing me with all options for the target and owner spaces so I can batch change these either by doing all of the constraints on all of the bones or doing a specific type of constraint (Such as Copy Transform)
If anyone knows any good tutorials or anything that can point me in the vague direction of how on earth I've fucked up I'd be greatly appreciative, bellow is a segments of the code I think might be responsible?
class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    ExistingBoneConstraints_enum : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name = "",
        description = "",
        items = [("1", "Test One", "Working?"), ("2", "Test Two", "Fuck You")],
        update = von_buttoncontrols.getselectedbonesforenum #See post directly under for all relevant code
    ) # type: ignore


class VonPanel_RiggingTools_Submenu_MassSetBoneConstraintSpace(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "von.masssetboneconstraintspace"
    bl_label = "Mass Set Constraint Space"


    def execute(self, context):
        print("Yay??")
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool=scene.my_tool

        layout.prop(mytool.ExistingBoneConstraints_enum)



class VonPanel_RiggingTools(VonPanel, bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "von.vontools"
    bl_label = "Rigging Tools"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        scene = context.scene
        mytool=scene.my_tool

        row.label(text= "Bone Manipulation", icon= 'CUBE')
        #Colorize Rig

        #Bone Search
        layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'
        layout.operator("von.popoutpanelbonesearch")
        

        row.label(text= "Bone Shapes", icon= 'CUBE')
        #create object
        layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'
        layout.operator("von.addcustomboneshape")
        layout.operator("von.savenewcontrol")
        layout.operator("von.masssetboneconstraintspace")
        


        row.label(text= "Weight Painting", icon= 'CUBE')



def von_menupopup_register():
    print(f'Menu File Initiated')
    from bpy.utils import register_class # type: ignore
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)


Fixed it -- Incase anyone wants to see the fixed shit cause they ended up in the same hole I've been in for the past 32 hours ---
    ExistingBoneConstraints_enum : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name = "",
        description = "",
        items = von_buttoncontrols.getselectedbonesforenum,
        update = updateexistingboneconstraintsenum
    ) # type: ignore

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #    Dynamic Enum Population
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateexistingboneconstraintsenum(self, context):
        print("Update Enum!!!")
        von_buttoncontrols.getselectedbonesforenum(self, context)

    class VonPanel_RiggingTools_Submenu_MassSetBoneConstraintSpace(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "von.masssetboneconstraintspace"
    bl_label = "Mass Set Constraint Space"
 
    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool=scene.my_tool

        enum = mytool.ExistingBoneConstraints_enum
        print("ENUM IS")
        print(enum)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool=scene.my_tool
        enum = mytool.ExistingBoneConstraints_enum
        layout.prop(mytool, "ExistingBoneConstraints_enum")

     class VonPanel_RiggingTools(VonPanel, bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "von.vontools"
    bl_label = "Rigging Tools"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        layout.operator("von.masssetboneconstraintspace")

    def von_menupopup_register():
    print(f'Menu File Initiated')
    from bpy.utils import register_class # type: ignore
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)



def von_menupopup_unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class # type: ignore
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
```


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
